# Why is .object_id in ruby sometimes returning positive or negative numbers?

Tags: ruby

I get this for a nil object in Ruby (**irb**):

```
nil.object_id # => 4
```

But for a string, I get negative results:

```
"abc".object_id # => -570954278
"abc".object_id # => -570956148
```

I am confused about the negative part. Is this proper or have I done something strange?

My ruby is:

```
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [i686-linux]
```

Comment: http://ei-lene.github.io/blog/2013/02/19/q-and-a-quickie-about-object-ids/

Comment: What is wrong with negative numbers?

Answer (score 0):

The number effectively is a signed integer, with one bit used for sign and the rest used for data. See [here](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2009/04/21/object-ids-and-fixnums/) for a discussion on some finer points of its implementation, mentioning the positive and negative storage.

But to be short, no, there isn't anything to worry about.